# How Do You Make Team Spawn Points?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do I create a random team chooser for Minecraft?
answers helped me out a lot with my KitPVP Teams map but I have one more thing I need to do. I have to make the teams spawn in different areas. In more detail, I need command blocks to tp you to your team's spawn point when you join the team. I've tried having two command blocks set to **impulse** **unconditional** **AlwaysActive** that have the command:

```
/tp @a[team=(team name)] (xyz)
```

This isn't working and I can't think of anything else that would work. Changing it to repeat would make you frozen in the spawn point. Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using a button/pressure plate to toggle the command block then set the options to 
<kbd>Impulse</kbd> <kbd>Unconditional</kbd> <kbd>Needs redstone</kbd>

If it is being executed after another command block it needs to be set to 
<kbd>Chain</kbd> <kbd>Conditional</kbd> <kbd>Always Active</kbd>

Your command: `/tp @a[team=(team name)] <x> <y> <z>` uses the proper [target selector](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Selecting_targets_by_team).

It sounds like you are new to command blocks.  I highly recommend you visit the wiki pages for [commands](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands) and [command blocks](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Command_Block), they contain lots of valuable information.  I reference them a lot when building various command block creations.

Comment: I'm not new to command blocks. Really, I'm not. I just am not an expert on them

Comment: Trust me, if you have problems with something like this, you are a beginner compared to a lot of other people. And there's always more to learn. For example I haven't even learned `/stats` yet and now there's new commands in 1.13. `/tp` is a beginner difficulty command.

Comment: I didn't mean anything negative by using the term beginner.  Everyone has to start somewhere.  I was just meaning the commands wiki is very useful.  I reference it often.

Comment: ok. I've been using command blocks ever since I discovered them 1 year after I got Minecraft. I've now been using them for 3-4 years but I admit I've still got a lot to learn. I wasn't offended by the term beginner in any way. I'll take a look at the command wiki I guess